# Atualizar dados do widget - tempo atualização

Tags: android, widget

Estou criando uma aplicação que terá um widget, nele serão apresentados alguns dados pegos de um webservice. Preciso que ele atualize a cada 5 min para ter uma informação recente ao usuário.

A documentação do 
[AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis) diz que as requisições de atualização serão feitas somente acima de 30 min, nada abaixo disso, para poupar bateria e uso desnecessário.

Andei pesquisando, e no stack em inglês, é citado uma [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310264/frequently-updating-widgets-more-frequently-than-what-updateperiodmillis-allows) utilizando o AlarmManager para resolver.

Não sei qual a melhor maneira de tratar isso e se há alguma maneira de fazer a atualização em tempos menores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [solução encontrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310264/frequently-updating-widgets-more-frequently-than-what-updateperiodmillis-allows) do `AlarmManager` não é de se ignorar. Os benefícios desta abordagem é a possibilidade de configurar o tempo de atualização, e também [lidar com o caso do dispositivo "dormir"](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#tradeoffs). Porém tem que se pensar se realmente é necessário que o tempo de atualização seja diferente da [sugestão que consta documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis). Hoje em dia ainda temos esse problema de bateria, no qual um dispositivo, mesmo em *standby*, consome uma quantidade considerável de carga.

Lançar muitas atualizações para *widgets* acaba se tornando uma ameaça ao seu *app*, pois caso ele **não esteja** entre os mais úteis instalados no dispositivo, o usuário pode vir a desfazer de sua aplicação, desinstalando-o. Realmente é necessário reavaliar essa questão em relação da necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @acklay, minha aplicação precisaria de refresh em tempos menores, pois atualizaria dados da bolsa. No momento vou ver a solução com AlarmManager e pensar em outra forma de resolver isso.